# Creating a file unsing openFileOutput() which is visible to other applications

Tags: android

I'm using the openFileOutput() to create a new txt file. I need the file to be visible from other applications (as well as from a PC when the Android device is connected via USB. Ive tried using .setReadable(true); but this does not seem valid. Please advise how I should declare the file is visible / public.

```
 try {
                   textIncoming.append("saving");
                   final String STORETEXT = "test.txt";
                   OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT, 0));
                   out.setReadable(true);
                   out.write("testing");
                   out.close();
               }
               catch (Throwable t) {
                   textIncoming.append("not saving");
               }
```

Ive changed my program to use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), but for some reason it returns a path /storage/emulated/0/Documents, and I cant even find this folder on the device. Ive looked at the files on the android device using ES file explorer but cant find the folder or file I'm trying to create (Plus I want these in an documents folder on the SD card, so it seems that its not giving me a pointer to the SD card at all, and not creating the folder, and not creating the file. Following is my updated code, please advise

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/Saved_Receipts");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "DRcpt-" + n + ".xml";
                textIncoming.append(root);
                File file = new File(myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it to sdcard if you want anyone to be able to read it.
This android documentation should tell you what you need to do.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: okay, I see how to access external storage, but not how to actually point to one of the folders to actually create a file, and to write to that file. It appears that the OutputStreamWriter .setReadable and .write are not supported for external memory ?

Answer (score 0):

openFileOutput() [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)) says:

> Open a private file

So the file that it creates won't be visible to other apps, unless you copy it to another directory that is visible.  In that case, you have to save your data in what's called "external storage" which is shared with other apps.  Use the code at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage).